# Change matched color in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, themes, resharper, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with Resharper and Nightowl theme.

I have a problem with colors:

[image]

How can I change colors to solve my problem?

When Resharper is disabled, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Resharper, you must apply changes to Resharper settings.

> tools> options> Enviroment > Fonts and Colors:

- Resharper Usage of element under cursor
- or Resharper Highlight
- or other resharpre options.

You can try the options.

[image: other resharpre options]